# Plotting a list of lines in Mathematica and trimming to an area

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have specified some lines in a list for example

```
linelist = {Line[{{-390, 1}, {1690, 1}}], 
  Line[{{-390, 40}, {1690, 40}}], Line[{{-390, 79}, {1690, 79}}], 
  Line[{{-390, 118}, {1690, 118}}], Line[{{-390, 781}, {1690, 781}}], 
  Line[{{-390, 820}, {1690, 820}}], Line[{{-390, 859}, {1690, 859}}], 
  Line[{{-390, 898}, {1690, 898}}], Line[{{-498, 460}, {1185, 1682}}],
   Line[{{-521, 491}, {1162, 1714}}], 
  Line[{{-544, 523}, {1139, 1745}}], 
  Line[{{-567, 554}, {1116, 1777}}], 
  Line[{{-590, 586}, {1093, 1809}}], 
  Line[{{-613, 617}, {1070, 1840}}], 
  Line[{{-636, 649}, {1047, 1872}}], 
  Line[{{-659, 681}, {1024, 1903}}], 
  Line[{{946, -541}, {1588, 1437}}], 
  Line[{{908, -528}, {1551, 1449}}], 
  Line[{{871, -517}, {1514, 1462}}], 
  Line[{{834, -504}, {1477, 1473}}], 
  Line[{{797, -493}, {1440, 1486}}], 
  Line[{{760, -481}, {1402, 1498}}], 
  Line[{{723, -469}, {1366, 1510}}], 
  Line[{{686, -457}, {1328, 1522}}], 
  Line[{{1291, -237}, {648, 1741}}], 
  Line[{{1255, -250}, {611, 1729}}], 
  Line[{{1217, -261}, {575, 1717}}], 
  Line[{{1181, -274}, {538, 1705}}], 
  Line[{{1143, -285}, {501, 1693}}], 
  Line[{{1107, -296}, {463, 1681}}], 
  Line[{{1069, -309}, {427, 1668}}], 
  Line[{{1032, -321}, {389, 1657}}], Line[{{995, -333}, {352, 1646}}],
   Line[{{958, -345}, {316, 1633}}], 
  Line[{{1002, -638}, {-680, 584}}], Line[{{979, -668}, {-703, 553}}]}

Graphics@linelist
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to iterate through each line to perform a test, for example the distance from the 0,0 coordinate.

Also, the end points are outside of my area of concern. I would like to constrain the lines to a boxed area, say from -1600,-1600 to 1600, 1600

I've been playing with this for hours and trying to make a for loop work for the Line statements, but, then I can't get them back on the same graph.

The plot I get without clipping is:
[image: Graphic representation of linelist]

The plot I get with clipping works for horizontal lines, but, the slanted lines are no longer parallel. (from suggested answer below)

```
newlinelist = Map[({{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = #[[1]];
    Line[{{Clip[x1, {0, 1300}], 
       Clip[y1, {0, 1300}]}, {Clip[x2, {0, 1300}], 
       Clip[y2, {0, 1300}]}}]) &, linelist]
```

[image: linelist with map and clipping as suggested]

Comment: I tried 'Graphics[linelist, PlotRange -> {{-1600, -1600}, {1600, 1600}}, 
 PlotRange -> True, Frame -> True]' But the lines do not show on the graphic

Comment: I tried
For[i = 1, i <= Length[linelist], i++,
 {Print[Part[linelist, i]],
  p[i] = Part[linelist, i]}
 ]

Comment: With For[i = 1, i <= Length[linelist], i++, Print[p[i]]] , in hopes to do something like Show[p1,p2,...,p36]. But, I can't get all of them to populate in the same Show statement

Comment: This is what I was attempting:   Show[For[i = 1, i <= Length[linelist], i++, Graphics@p[i]]]

Answer (score 0):

Other kinds of programming languages depend heavily on you writing `For` loops. It is possible to do that in Mathematica, but there are other ways to do things. For example:

```
linelist={
Line[{{-390,1},{1690,1}}],Line[{{-390,40},{1690,40}}],Line[{{-390,79},{1690,79}}],
Line[{{-390,118},{1690,118}}],Line[{{-390,781},{1690,781}}],Line[{{-390,820},{1690,820}}],
Line[{{-390,859},{1690,859}}],Line[{{-390,898},{1690,898}}],Line[{{-498,460},{1185,1682}}],
Line[{{-521,491},{1162,1714}}],Line[{{-544,523},{1139,1745}}],Line[{{-567,554},{1116,1777}}],
Line[{{-590,586},{1093,1809}}],Line[{{-613,617},{1070,1840}}],Line[{{-636,649},{1047,1872}}],
Line[{{-659,681},{1024,1903}}],Line[{{946,-541},{1588,1437}}],Line[{{908,-528},{1551,1449}}],
Line[{{871,-517},{1514,1462}}],Line[{{834,-504},{1477,1473}}],Line[{{797,-493},{1440,1486}}],
Line[{{760,-481},{1402,1498}}],Line[{{723,-469},{1366,1510}}],Line[{{686,-457},{1328,1522}}],
Line[{{1291,-237},{648,1741}}],Line[{{1255,-250},{611,1729}}],Line[{{1217,-261},{575,1717}}],
Line[{{1181,-274},{538,1705}}],Line[{{1143,-285},{501,1693}}],Line[{{1107,-296},{463,1681}}],
Line[{{1069,-309},{427,1668}}],Line[{{1032,-321},{389,1657}}],Line[{{995,-333},{352,1646}}],
Line[{{958,-345},{316,1633}}],Line[{{1002,-638},{-680,584}}],Line[{{979,-668},{-703,553}}]};
newlinelist=Map[({{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}=#[[1]];
  Line[{{Clip[x1,{-1600,1600}],Clip[y1,{-1600,1600}]},
        {Clip[x2,{-1600,1600}],Clip[y2,{-1600,1600}]}}])&,linelist
]
```

returns

```
{Line[{{-390,1},{1600,1}}],Line[{{-390,40},{1600,40}}],Line[{{-390,79},{1600,79}}],
 Line[{{-390,118},{1600,118}}],Line[{{-390,781},{1600,781}}],Line[{{-390,820},{1600,820}}],
 Line[{{-390,859},{1600,859}}],Line[{{-390,898},{1600,898}}],Line[{{-498,460},{1185,1600}}],
 Line[{{-521,491},{1162,1600}}],Line[{{-544,523},{1139,1600}}],Line[{{-567,554},{1116,1600}}],
 Line[{{-590,586},{1093,1600}}],Line[{{-613,617},{1070,1600}}],Line[{{-636,649},{1047,1600}}],
 Line[{{-659,681},{1024,1600}}],Line[{{946,-541},{1588,1437}}],Line[{{908,-528},{1551,1449}}],
 Line[{{871,-517},{1514,1462}}],Line[{{834,-504},{1477,1473}}],Line[{{797,-493},{1440,1486}}],
 Line[{{760,-481},{1402,1498}}],Line[{{723,-469},{1366,1510}}],Line[{{686,-457},{1328,1522}}],
 Line[{{1291,-237},{648,1600}}],Line[{{1255,-250},{611,1600}}],Line[{{1217,-261},{575,1600}}],
 Line[{{1181,-274},{538,1600}}],Line[{{1143,-285},{501,1600}}],Line[{{1107,-296},{463,1600}}],
 Line[{{1069,-309},{427,1600}}],Line[{{1032,-321},{389,1600}}],Line[{{995,-333},{352,1600}}],
 Line[{{958,-345},{316,1600}}],Line[{{1002,-638},{-680,584}}],Line[{{979,-668},{-703,553}}]}
```

What that does is use the `Map` function which takes a list and another
function to apply to each item in that list and it returns a list of the
results. What that function does for your application is extract the x1,y1,x2,y2 values out of your `Line` and then uses the Mathematica `Clip` function to constrain the values and finally constructs a new `Line` with the new values.

That `#` and `&` function stuff may be difficult for a new user to understand.

Here is an alternate way of writing that which should do the same thing.

```
f[Line[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}}]]:=Line[{{Clip[x1,{-1600,1600}],Clip[y1,{-1600,1600}]},
  {Clip[x2,{-1600,1600}],Clip[y2,{-1600,1600}]}}];
newlinelist=Map[f,linelist]
```

You should verify that it did correctly trim each of your lines
to lie in the -1600...1600 box that you desired.

I am a little worried about the result. If you compare these two graphics

```
Graphics[linelist]
Graphics[newlinelist]
```

you can see that the upper part of those are different and it doesn't seem to just be because of trimming the ranges of x and y. Notice that some of the lines are no longer parallel in the second one. You should try to convince yourself if that is what you really want or not.

A completely different way of getting the different graphic, but without changing the underlying list of lines, is to compare these two

```
Graphics[linelist]
Graphics[linelist,PlotRange->{{-1600,1600},{-1600,1600}}]
```

Notice that all the lines remain parallel in the second one.

You wrote that you had tried using `PlotRange` without success and I think you should study exactly why that didn't work for you and whether this does work for you.

Comment: This is helpful, I am closer to what I need to get. I don't know how to add images here, so, I'll put them in the original post.

Comment: Using this adjusted code:
newlinelist = Map[({{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = #[[1]];
    Line[{{Clip[x1, {0, 1300}], 
       Clip[y1, {0, 1300}]}, {Clip[x2, {0, 1300}], 
       Clip[y2, {0, 1300}]}}]) &, linelist]

The graphic forces the slanted lines to no longer be parallel

Comment: Yea, I was afraid I would have to do that. I'm trying to write a function now that will give me the intersection points of each line on the box